# Swift 4 from Swift 3 Conversion - Void Expects 2 arguments

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I am getting an error in Swift 4 but not too sure what Xcode is expecting.

This code:

```
_connection.on(method: "locationUpdate", callback: {(locationUpdate: LocationUpdate) in
      self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate)
  })
```

Produces this error:

> Contextual closure type '([Any?], TypeConverter) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
_connection.on(method: "locationUpdate", callback: { locationUpdate, other in
      self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate)
  })
```

**OR**

```
_connection.on(method: "locationUpdate") { locationUpdate, other in
   self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate)
}
```

If you do not want to use the `other` argument best practice is to not assign it, as follows:

```
_connection.on(method: "locationUpdate") { locationUpdate, _ in
   self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate)
}
```